# How to force axes labels onto a scatter plot of only np.nan floats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, scatter-plot

So I have a loop that is creating different charts from different dataframes in different files.

I noticed that in a few iteration outputs, the resulting graph has no x or y axis label when all the values  in the dataframe are NaNs.

*Note: axes labels are applied correctly to dataframes with actual floats and integer values.*

How can I force python to apply labels to an empty graph?

Here is an example

```
test = {'one':['2s','3s','4s'],
       'two':[2,4,5],
       'three':[6,3,5],
       'four':[5,7,2],
       'five':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
       'six':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
xx = pd.DataFrame(test)
xy = xx.set_index('one')
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=xy.iloc[:,3], y=xy.iloc[:,4], data=xy, ci=None).set(title='test')
```

Comment: `ax = sns.scatterplot(x=xy.iloc[:,3], y=xy.iloc[:,4], data=xy, ci=None)`, `ax.set_title('test')`, `ax.set_ylabel('foo')`, `ax.set_xlabel('bar')`?

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't know what the column labels are. I'm looping through over 30 files to create plots. I guess I'll edit my program to account for this. Thanks for input

Comment: What about `ax.set_xlabel(xy.columns[3])` and `ax.set_ylabel(xy.columns[4])`?